# Not able to populate form with server copy of json array without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to populate my form with the server copy of my json array, but it seems to be pulling from the local copy. Right now I have a function that populates the form when I click on a rectangle (each of which represents a `json` object in the array).

For example, if I change the select option `attributeName` on the form and submit, it saves the change correctly to the server in the `json` array, but when I click on a different rectangle and come back to the rectangle with the change, it doesn't populate the form field with the change (doesn't pull from the server json array).

If I load a different array, or if I refresh the page, then it works...how can I get my local copy of the array to reflect the change without refreshing?

Here is the function:

```
$(function() {
  function populateForm() {

    var matchingWidth = $('#canvas-overlay > .rectangle.targeted').width();
    $(".rectangle.null").each(function() {
      if ($(this).width() === matchingWidth) {
        var ID_clicked = $(this).attr('id');

        // populate form function
        function populate(frm, data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, value){
              var ctrl = $('[name='+key+']', frm);
                    switch(ctrl.prop("type")) {
                        case "radio": case "checkbox":
                            ctrl.each(function() {
                                if($(this).attr('value') == value) {
                                  $(this).prop("checked", true);
                                  $("#attribute-form .ui.radio.checkbox").removeClass('checked');
                                  $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        default:
                            ctrl.val(value);
                    }
            });
          }
          var selection = $('#templateSelection > option:selected').text();
          // create variable for and expose JSON
          var json = (function () {
            var json = null;
            $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': 'server/php/data/' + selection,
                'dataType': "json",
                'success': function (data) {
                    json = data;
                }
            });
            return json;
          })();
          // search json for index value that matches id clicked
          // and populate form with associated object
          json.some(function(e) {
            if (e.ID === ID_clicked) {

                var values = json.map(function(e) { return e.ID; });
                var index = json.map(function(e) { return e.ID; }).indexOf(ID_clicked);

                var data = JSON.stringify(json[index]);
                populate('#attribute-form', $.parseJSON(data));

                return true; // stops the "loop"
            }
          });
        }
      });
  }
  $(document).on('click', '#canvas-overlay > .rectangle', function() {
    $('#canvas-overlay > .rectangle').removeClass('targeted');
    $(this).addClass('targeted');
    populateForm();
  });
});
```

and for reference here is process.php which is the action when submitting:

```
<?php

   $filename = $_POST['store-template-name'];
   $myFile = "data/" . $filename;
   $arr_data = array(); // create empty array

  try
  {
       //Get form data
       $formdata = array(
          'ID'=> $_POST['ID'],
          'attributeName'=> $_POST['attributeName']
       );
       //Get data from existing json file
       $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);
       // converts json data into array
       $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
       $updateKey = null;
       foreach ($arr_data as $k => $v) {
            if ($v['ID'] == $formdata['ID']) {
                $updateKey = $k;
            }
        }
        if ($updateKey === null) {
            array_push($arr_data,$formdata);
        } else {
            $arr_data[$updateKey] = $formdata;
        }

       $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data);

       if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
            echo 'Data successfully saved';
        }
       else
            echo "error";
   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }
?>
```

Comment: `&.ajax` is async, you need to update the html inside of the `success` callback.

Comment: get requests cache.... look at the jquery  documentation for cache breaking.

Comment: @Josh OP is making a synchronous call, bad idea, but that is what the code is doing.

Comment: @epascarello oh i didn't see that property in the ajax object. Good eye.

Comment: @epascarello, I'd like to get rid of the `async`, but if I do that and comment out `$updateKey = null;` then the `var json` returns as undefined. The function just errors out. Ideas on how to rewrite?

Comment: @Josh, I'm fairly new to PHP and ajax. Should I use something like `$("#attribute-form").html(result);` in the success callback?

Comment: Yes, you use the success callback to run the next step. IT is the basic idea behind promises.

Comment: @epascarello As far as the 'next step' are you referring to `$(document).on('click'....` and everything after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get requests are cached, either have serverside set proper no cache headers or set cache to false in jQuery.

```
         $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            cache: false,
            'url': 'server/php/data/' + selection,
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
```

And do yourself a favor and refactor your code to not by synchronous. Synchronous calls are a bad idea. The code after the json code should live in the success callback or use `done` which is the recommended way with jQuery.